# How to stop JavaScript progress bar at a certain point

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress

I'm using the example progress bar shown in [W3Schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_progressbar_label_js).

How would I make the progress bar stop at a fixed point, let's say, 90%? I see that it has something to do with the width of the bar, but I can't figure out how to change it to a fixed point, or even a variable.

```js
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);

  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++;
      elem.style.width = width + '%';
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1 + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#myProgress {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
#myBar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
#label {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript Progress Bar</h1>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">
    <div id="label">10%</div>
  </div>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="move()">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: `if (width >= 90)` -- Though personally I would use the `<progress>` element.

Comment: It's actualy the condition width >= 100 you can set it to 90 if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the condition to `width >= 90`.

Code:

```
function move() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");   
  var width = 10;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
  function frame() {
    /* CHANGE THIS TO 90 */
    if (width >= 90) {
      clearInterval(id);
    } else {
      width++; 
      elem.style.width = width + '%'; 
      document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = width * 1  + '%';
    }
  }
}
```

Working sample: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/vLfhno9x/

Comment: Thank you! That was a very helpful response :)